# SSL connect error in woocommerce though 'Force secure checkout' is disabled

Tags: wordpress, ssl, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I'm using woocommerce 2.3.13 on my development environment with paypal sandbox mode. as its not yet SSL certified so under `Checkout > 'Force secure checkout'` is disabled now.

but on checkout page its still showing "SSL connect error" while trying to connect to paypal sandbox.

Is anyone face the same issue?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Paypal have recently rolled out some security updates on the sandbox (production will be updated in June) https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/

Most importantly, TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are no longer accepted by the sandbox, so you'll need to make sure that TLS 1.2 is being used by forcing the curl option, e.g:

`$curl->setOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,6);`

You'll need OpenSSL 1.0.1+ for this to work. You can wait for woocommerce to release a patch themselves, or perhaps try updating to PHP 5.5.19+ and (lib)curl 7.34+ so that the "common encryption algorithm" handshake can find TLS 1.2 and use it automatically, but I haven't tested that yet.

Comment: If your server software is updated accordingly you should not have to force the SSLVERSION in curl.  The server software would fall back to the working version on its own.

Comment: Yep, I didn't update my answer after testing but I did confirm that TLS 1.2 will automatically kick in with PHP 5.5.19+ and curl 7.29+. Unfortunately, many projects are still on PHP 5.3/5.4 which doesn't knows about TLS 1.2, so forcing the SSL version is necessary in some cases.