# IPN Response: WP_Error Object, SSL connect error, Error response: SSL connect error

Tags: ssl, paypal, woocommerce, ssl-certificate, paypal-ipn

We have multiple Woo Commerce stores set up however one we have a SSL Certificate applied to it.

On the one with the SSL certificate we get the Error "Error response: SSL connect error" in the Woo Commerce pay pal Logs. Has anyone got any clue as to what the reason could be.

I have tried changing the notify URL to a http connection instead but it still produces the same issue.

WooCommerce PayPal Log below

```
  01-29-2016 @ 10:25:25 - Generating payment form for order 1869. Notify URL: https://frictionfreeshaving.com/wc-api/WC_Gateway_Paypal/
01-29-2016 @ 10:25:48 - Checking IPN response is valid
01-29-2016 @ 10:25:48 - IPN Request: Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [cmd] => _notify-validate
            [transaction_subject] => Subscription 1870 (Order 1869) - test-razor
            [payment_date] => 02:25:44 Jan 29, 2016 PST
            [txn_type] => subscr_payment
            [subscr_id] => I-0TFMV85ERGCJ
            [last_name] => singh
            [residence_country] => GB
            [item_name] => Subscription 1870 (Order 1869) - test-razor
            [payment_gross] => 
            [mc_currency] => GBP
            [business] => tjmailcoms@gmail.com
            [payment_type] => instant
            [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
            [verify_sign] => ALUw10OT3.wkDPQ73JiKtXApC16gA24mWOunWinyGFBel4bkL0L8u3O-
            [payer_status] => verified
            [test_ipn] => 1
            [payer_email] => tjmailcoms03@gmail.com
            [txn_id] => 41285066KK228700R
            [receiver_email] => tjmailcoms@gmail.com
            [first_name] => tejinder
            [invoice] => WC-10011869
            [payer_id] => M7A8DVMKC4GCW
            [receiver_id] => XK2LNP4PTGQUU
            [payment_status] => Completed
            [payment_fee] => 
            [mc_fee] => 0.23
            [mc_gross] => 1.00
            [custom] => {"order_id":1869,"order_key":"wc_order_56ab3e14c01b3","subscription_id":1870,"subscription_key":"wc_order_56ab3e14e7922"}
            [charset] => windows-1252
            [notify_version] => 3.8
            [ipn_track_id] => f7146428bb012
        )

    [timeout] => 60
    [httpversion] => 1.1
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 
    [user-agent] => WooCommerce/2.3.11
)

01-29-2016 @ 10:25:48 - IPN Response: WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SSL connect error
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)

01-29-2016 @ 10:25:48 - Received invalid response from PayPal
01-29-2016 @ 10:25:48 - Error response: SSL connect error
01-29-2016 @ 10:25:52 - Checking IPN response is valid
01-29-2016 @ 10:25:53 - IPN Request: Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [cmd] => _notify-validate
            [txn_type] => subscr_signup
            [subscr_id] => I-0TFMV85ERGCJ
            [last_name] => singh
            [residence_country] => GB
            [mc_currency] => GBP
            [item_name] => Subscription 1870 (Order 1869) - test-razor
            [business] => tjmailcoms@gmail.com
            [recurring] => 1
            [verify_sign] => AFUzd6d5BFLcPs.756upyW0L6Uo6A-NLMyaoJ69kQZg1yL4yEsY4gTMf
            [payer_status] => verified
            [test_ipn] => 1
            [payer_email] => tjmailcoms03@gmail.com
            [first_name] => tejinder
            [receiver_email] => tjmailcoms@gmail.com
            [payer_id] => M7A8DVMKC4GCW
            [invoice] => WC-10011869
            [reattempt] => 1
            [subscr_date] => 02:25:42 Jan 29, 2016 PST
            [custom] => {"order_id":1869,"order_key":"wc_order_56ab3e14c01b3","subscription_id":1870,"subscription_key":"wc_order_56ab3e14e7922"}
            [charset] => windows-1252
            [notify_version] => 3.8
            [period3] => 1 D
            [mc_amount3] => 1.00
            [ipn_track_id] => f7146428bb012
        )

    [timeout] => 60
    [httpversion] => 1.1
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 
    [user-agent] => WooCommerce/2.3.11
)

01-29-2016 @ 10:25:53 - IPN Response: WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SSL connect error
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)

01-29-2016 @ 10:25:53 - Received invalid response from PayPal
01-29-2016 @ 10:25:53 - Error response: SSL connect error
01-29-2016 @ 10:30:08 - Checking IPN response is valid
01-29-2016 @ 10:30:09 - IPN Request: Array
(
    [body] => Array
        (
            [cmd] => _notify-validate
            [txn_type] => subscr_cancel
            [subscr_id] => I-0TFMV85ERGCJ
            [last_name] => singh
            [residence_country] => GB
            [mc_currency] => GBP
            [item_name] => Subscription 1870 (Order 1869) - test-razor
            [business] => tjmailcoms@gmail.com
            [recurring] => 1
            [verify_sign] => Am729F3QdZ4ucintGF7EZMXFQKlgAKfHAWYr4ohDcQkhr0xx0H34n8lT
            [payer_status] => verified
            [test_ipn] => 1
            [payer_email] => tjmailcoms03@gmail.com
            [first_name] => tejinder
            [receiver_email] => tjmailcoms@gmail.com
            [payer_id] => M7A8DVMKC4GCW
            [invoice] => WC-10011869
            [reattempt] => 1
            [subscr_date] => 02:29:50 Jan 29, 2016 PST
            [custom] => {"order_id":1869,"order_key":"wc_order_56ab3e14c01b3","subscription_id":1870,"subscription_key":"wc_order_56ab3e14e7922"}
            [charset] => windows-1252
            [notify_version] => 3.8
            [period3] => 1 D
            [mc_amount3] => 1.00
            [ipn_track_id] => 542b79c8e6b4
        )

    [timeout] => 60
    [httpversion] => 1.1
    [compress] => 
    [decompress] => 
    [user-agent] => WooCommerce/2.3.11
)

01-29-2016 @ 10:30:09 - IPN Response: WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [http_request_failed] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SSL connect error
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)

01-29-2016 @ 10:30:09 - Received invalid response from PayPal
01-29-2016 @ 10:30:09 - Error response: SSL connect error
```

Due to this no orders are being processed but payment is being taken. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm out of ideas.

Tj

Comment: PayPal stopped accepting traffic over particular protocols as of 1/19/16 due to the [POODLE vulnerability](https://www.angelleye.com/php-curl-sslv3-vulnerability/).  There are lots of questions already answered about that, but it basically boils down to the fact that you need to update the OpenSSL, cURL, and Apache software stack in your web server environment.

Comment: @AndrewAngell thanks for that. Im presuming i will have to get intouch with our hosting provider for that? PS. Thanks for your Wordpress IPN plugin as we use that on other sites as well.

Comment: Glad it's working out for you (when the SSL thing isn't happening).  :)

Answer (score 2):

Copying my previous answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069397/ssl-connect-error-in-woocommerce-though-force-secure-checkout-is-disabled/35073780#35073780):

Paypal have recently rolled out some security updates on the sandbox (production will be updated in June) https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/

Most importantly, TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are no longer accepted by the sandbox, so you'll need to make sure that TLS 1.2 is being used by forcing the curl option, e.g:

$curl->setOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,6);

You'll need OpenSSL 1.0.1+ for this to work. You can wait for woocommerce to release a patch themselves, or you can make TLS 1.2 work automatically (the common cipher will be deduced during the SSL handshake) by updating to PHP 5.5.19+ and (lib)curl 7.34+.

Comment: actually i have the same problem. its not helping for me. i am using godaddy host.

Comment: Did you confirm that they are using OpenSSL 1.0.1? You can also find out from PHP by checking the value of `OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693614/how-to-check-if-installed-openssl-version-is-0-9-8k